# Obtain the symbol that a "super" call refers to in Scala

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, static-analysis, scala-compiler

I'm writing a Scala compiler plugin for the [refchecks](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SIW/Overview+of+Compiler+Phases) phase.

How do I access the [symbol](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html) that a "super" call refers to, given the symbol of the callsite?

For example, in

```
trait A {
  def m() {}
}

trait B extends A {
  def m() { super.m() }
}
```

knowing the symbol for the callsite `super.m()`, I would like to get the symbol for trait `A`.

Comment: are getClass() and classOf() for concrete instances and classes/types not what you want or not available at that phase?

Answer (score 1):

I think using of self type annotations and multiple inheritance will serve you:

```
trait HelperTrait {
  def helperMethod {println("calling helperMethod of HelperTrait")}
}

trait PublicInterface { this: HelperTrait =>
  def useHelperMethod 
  { 
    println("calling useHelperMethod of PublicInterface")
    helperMethod 
  }
}

class ImplementationClass extends PublicInterface with HelperTrait

var obj = new ImplementationClass()
obj.useHelperMethod
obj.helperMethod
```